# return derived class without overwrite

Tags: java, derived-class

Is something like this possible?

```
class A {

            this someMethod() {
                // code
                return this;
            }

        }


        class B extends A {

        }


        B b = new B();

        B b2 = b.someMethod();
```

This in the most simple way possible.

Comment: why you want this? if you want to have derived class from b, maybe b should holds instance of original A and delegate methods